# Is there a way to natively sync salesforce calendar with google calendar?

Tags: group-edition

We have a client with salesforce Group edition. He needs a way to link the salesforce calendar with his google calendar?

Can we do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of box approach.There is an appexchange product from Appirio

Appirio Cloud Sync for Google Apps

http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000004cg4GEAQ

This app has the feature of google calendar sync with salesforce

Comment: Hi Mohith, is there any app other than the one you listed above to achieve the same functionality

Comment: Hi Roshan i dont see any other app than this .I have tried this as a trial version for 30 days .Looks really nice .Its original cost is 4 dollar per month per user .

Comment: Thanks Mohith. Would you mind looking at this question. Looking for some answers : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/appointment-scheduling-apps

Comment: http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HuEBEA0     have a look at this app.Seems provide the same functionality

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use [Ebsta](http://www.ebsta.com/), because with this free extension for Chrome, you could easily (without doing anything) synchronize Google Calendar with Salesforce Calendar.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4xVrEAJ

Answer (score -1):

There's a Lightning for Gmail integration going live in Summer 17' that works pretty well. It's manual, but the Google extension is pretty clean and it's free. If you're on Classic look at your Administration section for Lightning Sync for Gmail. If in Lightning search Setup for the same. Use the help links (there are also some really good videos on YT if you search Lightning Sync for Gmail) to navigate directions.